# Debugging Self Host OWIN Middleware does not always run

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013, katana, owin-middleware

I have a simple console app to learn OWIN/Katana and I am stuck.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["url"];
        using (var app = WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Started listening on {0}", url);
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine("Stopping");
        }
    }
}
```

This starts up just fine and hits my using block.
[image: Console fired up ready to listen to requests]

I then see that my Startup is called:
[image: Use() Methods are being hit during debugging]

Next I startup Postman in Chrome and submit a GET Request. At this point my break points never get hit in either module.
[image: Postman GET setup]

No matter what changes I make it does not log my messages out to the console. Is there a way to find what is failing if anything? In Postman I do receive a HTTP 200 with a payload. The OwinMiddleware class is from the Microsoft.Owin namespace.

[image: Owin Middleware Module Components]

**EDIT**: Tech stack of the Project:

Website (Not Web Application) running AngularJs 1.4 using $resource.
WebApi 2.2 with OData V4

Running on .Net 4.5

Comment: Your `WebApiMiddleware` is before the `LoggingMiddleware` in the pipeline so the request may have been terminated there and may never reach the logging. Add the logging on top, before `StartupPrerequsites(app);` and try again.

Comment: @AngelYordanov That was exactly it. Please submit that as the answer so I can accept it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WebApiMiddleware` is before the `LoggingMiddleware` in the pipeline so the request may have been terminated there and may never reach the logging. Add the logging on top, before `StartupPrerequsites(app);` and try again.